# Setting MAX for Auto Increment ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, auto-increment

I have a table that imports 221 rows from a database table. Whenever I add a row dynamically inside the HTML Table page, I want it to be able to pull the MAX ID, so in this case 221, and add 1 to it, therefore bringing the MR_ID to 222. I need this because each ID must be unique. Whenever I add a row into the table and look at it in the database, it displays as NULL. I have a little something for that, but it doesn't seem to be working. If you need any more code than what I posted, let me know and I will provide it. Thank you!

```
<?php

  $MR_ID = $_POST['MR_ID'];
  $MR_Name = $_POST['MR_Name'];
  $Buyer_ID = $_POST['Buyer_ID'];
  $MR_POC_N = $_POST['MR_POC_N'];
  $MR_POC_E = $_POST['MR_POC_E'];
  $MR_POC_P = $_POST['MR_POC_P'];

  $host="xxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $MR_ID = "Select MAX(MR_ID) + 1 FROM Stage_Rebate_Master";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (MR_ID, MR_Name, Buyer_ID, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($MR_ID, $MR_Name, $Buyer_ID, $MR_POC_N, $MR_POC_E, $MR_POC_P));
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: max+1 is subject to race conditions.  Why not set the MR_ID to an identity or auto_increment and let the DB handle it to avoid race conditions?

Comment: I do have another column that auto increments as well and could be used as the actual ID....however this MR_ID column is used as a lookup throughout the database so I cant just have the NULL value

Comment: Seems like an odd way to relate tables on non-key values...  I suppose you could use a trigger to set the MR_ID to the auto-incremented value before update. (assuming this DBMS uses triggers)

Comment: I mean I would be fine with setting MR_ID column as auto increment or something like you said...from what I can see, it seems like the MR_ID is posting as 0 and is not seeing how many MR_IDs I actually have in order to do the MAX. And yes, the DBMS does use triggers.

Comment: Please tag your question with the brand of SQL database you are using. E.g. [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server], [tag:oracle], etc. The answer could depend on the implementation.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, did that!

Comment: Use a sequence instead. The `max()+1` anti-pattern is not going to work in an environment with concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Stage_Rebate_Master (MR_ID, MR_Name, Buyer_ID, MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P) SELECT  ISNULL(MAX(MR_ID)+1,1), ?, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM Stage_Rebate_Master";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute(array( $MR_Name, $Buyer_ID, $MR_POC_N, $MR_POC_E, $MR_POC_P));
```

Comment: Whenever I run this, I get an internal server error...im guessing it has something to do with the query